# Why does a vertical scrollbar appears in the parent of the iframe?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an iframe inside an element. The iframe should fill the whole element.

HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <iframe class="child" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Style definition:

```
.parent {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.child {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border: 0;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Unfortulately an unnecessary vertical scrollbar appears:

[image]

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4hqjt9w3/1/

How is it possible to get rid of the scrollbar on the parent element, without `overflow: hidden`, or absolute positioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the iframe a block element. By default its computed value of display is inline [so you will face a whitespace issue at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image) which will create the overflow:

[image]

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.child {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border: 0;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <iframe class="child" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean the scrolling attribute? Replace your code with the below.

```
<div class="parent">
  <iframe class="child" src="https://example.com" scrolling=no></iframe>
</div>
```