# Removing white space below iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to remove white space below my iframe when resizing. I am mainly using Bootstrap for CSS. The goal is to have the iframe take 100% of the page below the navbar.

[Example of iframe being cut off and white space trailing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtCkm.png)

This is how I am calling the iframe:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="site/index.html">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The only other element in the page is the navbar.

I have tried the following:
Changing the iframe to display:block
height and width:100%
overflow:hidden
overflow-y:hidden

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051985/why-does-a-vertical-scrollbar-appears-in-the-parent-of-the-iframe/51052023#51052023

Comment: share more CSS code

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `h-100` class for the `html` tag.
- Use `d-flex flex-column h-100` for the body.
- Use `flex-grow-1` for the `embed-responsive` so that it takes the rest of the available space.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <h1 class="mx-auto">iframe</h1>
  </nav>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://getbootstrap.com/">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

*You need to use bootstrap-4.1*

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!